# when properties are undefined, set a default value

Tags: javascript, object

Why is very single property set to 'undefined', although I write, when it's 'undefined', set it to a value?

```
var e = {
    f: function(g) {
        g    ===  'undefined'  ?  g    =  {} : {};
        g.h  ===  'undefined'  ?  g.h  =  1  : {};
        g.i  ===  'undefined'  ?  g.i  =  2  : {};

        console.log(g);

    }
};
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: FWIW, you are using the ternary `?:` *very suspiciously*. Don't use `?:` for side-effects (e.g. *don't* assign inside of it), but rather, use the return value of the expression: `g = g === undefined ? "default" : g`. I usually prefer to use the inverse though (such that positive is first): `g = g !== undefined ? g : "default"`. (Or better here, use a normal `if`.)

Comment: don't know, possibly a custom, but meanwhile I think, it's a bad custom in this case :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `undefined`, not `'undefined'`.

But you could write it in a clearer way :

```
if (g === undefined) g = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'undefined' === undefined
false

undefined === undefined
true
```

This is what my browser's JavaScript console has to say - try to remove the single quote markers around the "undefined". Seems like JavaScript's weak typing and automatic conversions only go so far!

Comment: +1 In this case I think using `x === undefined` is more appropriate than `typeof x === 'undefined'` because `x` is clearly bound in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use `typeof g === 'undefined'`, not `g === 'undefined'`.

[Documentation on `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

You could also do it using `g === undefined`

[Documentation on `undefined`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp)